SSD M.2 NVMe - Windows 10: How to know the Generation and number of lanes?
If a laptop or PC Desktop has a SSD M.2 NVMe
If is possible through Windows 10
Question

How to know the Generation and number of lanes?


Are you asking if this data can be queried or observed somewhere inside the OS, accessible to a script or other application, or how you can lookup this data? Are you asking a generic question about how to get this information for some sort of application or repeated process, or do you just want to find this data for a specific drive you have right now? Have you found the device serial or part number and looked up device documentation online? Please include further information in your question.

@music2myear "Are you asking if this data can be queried or observed somewhere inside the OS" Yes. "do you just want to find this data for a specific drive you have right now?" Yes - "Have you found the device serial or part number and looked up device documentation online?" consider the specs of the laptop/pcdesktop are not available in the web because is an old model. The original box of the machine does not exists and the stickers in the laptop are blank due the time. Finally to know if the "repairman" put the correct SSD. Thank You

You have to look to the processor and motherboard to determine this type of information. If you’re trying to query this information. What have you tried?

You can get drive serial and part numbers inside Windows. Look these up in the Device Manager, for one. I think Disk Management might also show this information.
